# Replacing the last two items from an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Following is the code which is working fine but I am interested if I can make this code more efficient and reduce the number of lines in my `replacementCountryLanguageCode` method using ES6 ?

My concern is about using `if else if` statements as somewhere I read that they are not efficient (I don't remember the source and may be the context was different, so apologies if that is the case with if else if).

```js
var url1 = "factory/news/fr/fr";
var url2 = "/factory/news/uk/en";
var url3 = "/region/factory/news/in/hi";

const replacementCountryLanguageCode = (url, countryCode, languageCode) => {
  const splitUrl = url.split("/");
  const splitUrlLength = splitUrl.length;
  let a = [];
  
  
  for( i= splitUrlLength-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(i === splitUrlLength-1) {
      a[splitUrlLength-1] = languageCode;
    }  
    else if(i === splitUrlLength-2) {
      a[splitUrlLength-2] = countryCode;
    } else {
      a[i] = splitUrl[i]
    }
  }
  
  const modifiedUrl = a.join("/");
  return modifiedUrl;
}

console.log( replacementCountryLanguageCode(url1, 'au', 'en') );
// Should return "factory/news/au/en"

console.log( replacementCountryLanguageCode(url2, 'fr', 'fr') );
// Should return "/factory/news/fr/fr"

console.log( replacementCountryLanguageCode(url3, 'es', 'es') );
// Should return "/region/factory/news/es/es"
```

Comment: array.slice(0,-2)

Comment: Don't do the replacement of the last two items inside the loop.  Just make the loop two shorter and replace the last two items after the loop.  You don't want the if/else inside the loop if it can be avoided (which it can).  Just shorten the `for` loop to not cover the last two items and then after the loop, just assign those last two items.  Also, you don't need a `for` loop to copy a bunch of items from an array, you can use `splitUrl.slice()` to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop the items, since you add them to exact indexes. Just slice after splitting using `.slice(0, -2)` (all items but the last two), spread, and add the codes:

```js
const url1 = "factory/news/fr/fr";
const url2 = "/factory/news/uk/en";
const url3 = "/region/factory/news/in/hi";

const replacementCountryLanguageCode = (url, countryCode, languageCode) => [
  ...url.split('/').slice(0, -2),
  languageCode,
  countryCode,
].join('/');

console.log(replacementCountryLanguageCode(url1, 'au', 'en'));
// Should return "factory/news/au/en"

console.log(replacementCountryLanguageCode(url2, 'fr', 'fr'));
// Should return "/factory/news/fr/fr"

console.log(replacementCountryLanguageCode(url3, 'es', 'es'));
// Should return "/region/factory/news/es/es"
```

Comment: or `return url.split("/").slice(0, -2).concat([languageCode, countryCode]).join('/')`

Comment: @HMR - btw you don't need to wrap elements you want to concat in an array `.concat(languageCode, countryCode)`. would be enough.

Comment: I really like this solution and I upvoted it, but you have to agree, that you have to have some experience with JS to read it. I am not sure if it would be understood by everyone.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's no good reason to put those `if` statements inside the loop. You could just as easily do

```
if (splitUrlLength-1 >= 0) {
    a[splitUrlLength-1] = languageCode;
}
if (splitUrlLength-2 >= 0) {
    a[splitUrlLength-2] = countryCode;
}
for (var i=splitUrlLength-3; i >= 0; i--) {
   a[i] = splitUrl[i];
}
```

This makes the loop much more efficient, as it doesn't have to test the conditions on each iteration any more.

However, you don't need that loop to copy the strings into a new array at all. You are not using the original `splitUrl` array for anything else, so you could just as well just mutate that:

```
function replacementCountryLanguageCode(url, countryCode, languageCode) {
    const splitUrl = url.split("/");
    const splitUrlLength = splitUrl.length;
    if (splitUrlLength-1 >= 0) {
        splitUrl[splitUrlLength-1] = languageCode;
    }
    if (splitUrlLength-2 >= 0) {
        splitUrl[splitUrlLength-2] = countryCode;
    }
    return splitUrl.join("/");
}
```

Now, if you can ensure that the `splitUrlLength` is always larger than 2, so you can *always* assign those last elements, you can simplify much more. Not just by omitting the `if` statements, but completely by using a chain of `slice` and `concat`:

```
function replacementCountryLanguageCode(url, countryCode, languageCode) {
    return url.split("/").slice(0, -2).concat([countryCode, languageCode]).join("/");
}
```

Comment: Your one liner function is wrong - https://jsbin.com/mukusobado/edit?js,console `slice(-2)` should be `slice(0, -2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it with `splice` method which allows deletion and addition of elements at same time.

Please find working example below:

```js
var url1 = "factory/news/fr/fr";
var url2 = "/factory/news/uk/en";
var url3 = "/region/factory/news/in/hi";

const replacementCountryLanguageCode = (url, countryCode, languageCode) => {
  const arr = url.split("/")
  arr.splice(arr.length-2, 2, countryCode, languageCode);
  const finalUrl = arr.join("/");
  return finalUrl;
}

console.log( replacementCountryLanguageCode(url1, 'au', 'en') );
// Should return "factory/news/au/en"

console.log( replacementCountryLanguageCode(url2, 'fr', 'fr') );
// Should return "/factory/news/fr/fr"

console.log( replacementCountryLanguageCode(url3, 'es', 'es') );
// Should return "/region/factory/news/es/es"
```

[Read about splice here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 0):

You can take the last two item assignments outside of the for loop which will simplify and speed up your code. Although, the speed increase is probably negligible unless you are working with a huge number of elements.

```js
var url1 = "factory/news/fr/fr";
var url2 = "/factory/news/uk/en";
var url3 = "/region/factory/news/in/hi";

const replacementCountryLanguageCode = (url, countryCode, languageCode) => {
  const splitUrl = url.split("/");
  const splitUrlLength = splitUrl.length;
  let a = [];
  
  a[splitUrlLength-1] = languageCode;
  a[splitUrlLength-2] = countryCode;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < splitUrlLength-2; i++) {
      a[i] = splitUrl[i];
  }
  
  return a.join("/");
}

console.log( replacementCountryLanguageCode(url1, 'au', 'en') );
console.log( replacementCountryLanguageCode(url2, 'fr', 'fr') );
console.log( replacementCountryLanguageCode(url3, 'es', 'es') );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use rest parameter `...` here with `reduceRight` method to create a function that can take any number of parameters and replace them in your url from the right to left.

```js
var url1 = "factory/news/fr/fr";
var url2 = "/factory/news/uk/en";
var url3 = "/region/factory/news/in/hi";

const replacementCountryLanguageCode = (string, ...params) => {
  return string.split('/').reduceRight((r, e) => {
    let str = params.pop()
    r.unshift(str ? str : e)
    return r
  }, []).join('/')
}

console.log( replacementCountryLanguageCode(url1, 'au', 'en') );
console.log( replacementCountryLanguageCode(url2, 'foo', '', 'fr') );
console.log( replacementCountryLanguageCode(url3, 'baz', 'es', 'es') );
```